# Javascript string replace regex proportion to occurence?

Tags: javascript, replace

I need to reduce the excessive line breaks from a string in Javascript.

Currently I have the following:

`generalsymptoms.replace(/(\s*\n\s*){6,}/g, '\n')`

this replaces 6 line breaks into 1, but this effectively makes original 5 line breaks have more gap than 6 line breaks.

Is it possible to reference the occurrence in the replace string, so I can use something like:

`generalsymptoms.replace(/(\s*\n\s*){6,}/g, '\n'.repeat(number_of_occurence/2))`

Comment: So you want to replace the number occurrences with half the original number of occurrences (e.g. `\n\n\n\n` => `\n\n`)?

Comment: half is just example, I might want to change the ratio later.

Comment: if it's by ratio, just use /\s\s/g where \s\s\s... the ratio you want.  doesn't sound like that's what you actually want though.  what you probably actually want is a `|` with a greedy selector on one side and a conservative one on the other

Comment: also, you realize that will replace spaces with newlines right?

Comment: yes that's what I expected, I have new line chars like '\n  \n\n  \n \n`

Comment: I see, but this will cause '  ' to also get replaced.  Just an fyi.

Comment: sorry I have made a mistake in regex, which I just updated

Answer (score 1):

```
' a a abaaaa'.replace(/(\s*a\s*){2,}/g, (matched, index, origin)=> {console.log(matched.replace(/\s/g, '')); return 'c'})
aaa
aaaa
```

which applied to here

```
generalsymptoms.replace(/(\n\s*\n){2,}/g, matched => '\n'.repeat(matched.replace(/ /g, '').length/2)))
```

Courtesy of my ex-colleague that hinted I can use a function in the replace method.

Comment: is that the solution to your problem?

Comment: isn't the second replace redundant?  that would just repeat(0) wouldn't it? was using repeat faster than just replacing sets of 2?

Comment: the second replace is to get rid of the spaces

Comment: right, I see that a second layer of regex would work for differentiating spaces, but \s includes \r \n and spaces?

Comment: oh right, oh thanks for pointing that out! I have updated my answer.